# Como manter a sessão após o fechamento do navegador?

Tags: php

Eu faço o login no meu site, mas, quando fecho o navegador, não tem mais sessão. Aí eu tenho que logar novamente.

Como resolvo isso ?

Comment: Nao ha como resolver isso amigo, essa é a característica da sessão, para manter isso use cookies

Comment: Tem como "resolver", mas você deve entender que session no php é cookie de sessão e o comportamento correto é este, deletar o cookie ao fechar o navegador. Talvez amanhã eu poste uma resposta.

Comment: Percebo que o pessoal gostam de fazer afirmações genéricas como "não tem como fazer isso" ou "não existe isso", mas isso dá pra resolver sim. Frameworks como laravel você configura se a sessão será destruída ao fechar o navegador ou por um período (2 horas por exemplo). Na verdade, você pode definir um lifetime para a sessão do php.

Comment: William, tomei a liberdade de editar o título. Acho que assim a descrição do seu problema fica mais detalhada.

Comment: A solução mais adequada é manter a sessão do PHP com o tempo normal, e fazer a persistência do que for mais importante em DB + Cookie separado (e recarregar quando a sessão "vence"). Num mundo ideal, bastaria aumentar a sessão do PHP com o `cookie_lifetime` junto do `gc_maxlifetime` (um só não basta), mas no "mundo real" não é simples assim.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No PHP a diretiva responsável pelo tempo da sessão no `php.ini` é o [`sesion.cookie_lifetime`](http://fi.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime).

Uma sessão usa um arquivo, na pasta temporária do php, cujo nome é um hash.

Por sua vez toda sessão usa um cookie. Por padrão é chamado de `PHPSESSID`. Nessa sessão é salva o nome do arquivo da sessão citado anteriormente.

A partir daí, os dados alocados em `$_SESSION` são salvos, serializados (sim, pela função `serialize` mesmo), nesse arquivo da sessão.

Assim, o PHP lê o valor do cookie  PHPSESSID e verifica se esse arquivo está na pasta de sessões. Se estiver, lê esses dados e os envia para a variável `$_SESSION`.

**E por que estou explicando isso?**

Algumas pessoas pensam que sessão não tem ligação com o cookie, mas tem. Tanto que se você apagar os cookies do navegador, como não vai ter a informação para ser capturada pelo php, o usuário da sessão será deslogado, por exemplo.

E, se o php usa, em partes, cookies na sessão, então você pode alterar a forma que esse cookie é configurado.

Como eu expliquei, a diretiva responsável pelo tempo de vida da sessão é o `session.cookie_lifetime`.

Por padrão o valor do mesmo é definido para `0` (zero). E todos sabemos que, se definirmos um cookie com o valor `0`, sua duração será apenas até o fechamento do navegador.

Isso posso ser percebido através da função `session_get_cookie_params`, que mostra como está a configuração atual do cookie de sessão do php.

Vamos lá:

```
 print_r(session_get_cookie_params());
```

Perceba o resultado:

```
Array
(
    [lifetime] => 0
    [path] => /
    [domain] => 
    [secure] => 
    [httponly] => 
)
```

**E como mudar isso?**

Use a função `session_set_cookie_params` para resolver isso. Para usá-la você **deve definir suas configurações antes da função `session_start`**.

Veja o "esqueleto da função":

```
void session_set_cookie_params (int $lifetime [,string $path [,string $domain [,bool $secure = false [,bool $httponly = false]]]] )
```

Apenas o parâmetro `$lifetime` é obrigatório. Então podemos usar essa função passando apenas o argumento que representará o tempo de vida da sessão.

Então, façamos assim:

```
$time = 2 * 60 * 60; // Defini 2 horas

session_set_cookie_params($time);
session_start();
```

Espero que isso ajude :D

## Links

- [session_set_cookie_params](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php)
- Outra alternativa para configuração (com ini_set, se você tiver acesso na sua hospedagem): [how to keep session after browser close](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15752506/3096922)

## Atualização

O autor da pergunta questionou-me a respeito de definir a sessão "infinitamente". A solução para isso é definir o valor máximo para int permitido pelo php como argumento de `session_set_cookie_params`. Vamos usar a constante `PHP_INT_MAX`.

Exemplo:

```
session_set_cookie_params(PHP_INT_MAX);
```

Comment: Funcionou :D, uma dúvida.. e para mim deixar a session permanente até que o o usuario clique em deslogar ou limpe os dados do navegador ?

Comment: @WilliamAlvares permanente seria através de uma gambiarra. Define como  100 anos, por exemplo, que funcionará. Exemplo: `60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 100`

Comment: Precisa ajustar e entender o funcionamento do session.gc_maxlifetime também, senão o arquivo da session pode ser eliminado antes do cookie.

Comment: E no caso, se a sessão tiver 100 anos, pode botar um belo HD na máquina pra guardar todas as sessões abertas...

Answer (score 0):

A sessão/session funciona da seguinte forma: Ela armazena os dados no navegador ou seja ela irá deixar os dados armazenados enquanto o navegador não for fechado, a partir do momento que o cliente fecha o navegador os dados da sessão são perdidos, Essa é exatamente a característica da sessão.

Para que você possa manter os dados mesmo após o fechamento do navegador use Cookies que é semelhante ao sessão/session porem a diferença é que o log é armazenado no computador do cliente, então todas as vezes que for requisitado a visita ao tal site ele verifica se tem algum cookies correspondente aquele site e se tiver ele já pega os dados salvos e faz a validação da forma correta.

para criar um Cookies a sintaxe é simples:

```
setcookie("nome_do_cookie", "valor_do_cookie");
```

porem como não é viável explicar aqui toda a forma de como usar o cookies desde o começo eu vou deixar aqui o link de referencia do php sobre cookies para você dar uma olhada e o link de um tutorial bem interessante, Boa sorte.

**Referencia php Cookies**: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.cookies.php

**Tutorial sobre uso de Cookies**: https://www.codigofonte.net/dicas/php/149_trabalhando-com-cookies-no-php

Comment: Afirmação errada: No php a sessão não é "salva no navegador", mas apenas o nome do arquivo da sessão é salvo no navegador.  Se fosse salvo no navegador, o usuário poderia alterar o valor da sessão (e isso seria muito ruim). Por isso faço questão de deixar isso claro aqui. E o problema de usar o cookie é que, dependendo do tamanho da informação que se deseja armazenar, ele não vai dar conta do recado.

Answer (score 0):

Olá...

Segui o comando abaixo, funcionou localmente, mas quando publico o site no servidor web, ele mantém o cookie para expirar quando fechar a sessão. Alguém sabe porque isso está acontecendo?

$time = 2 * 60 * 60; // Defini 2 horas

session_set_cookie_params($time);
session_start();

Comment: Se tiver uma nova pergunta, faça-a clicando no botão [Fazer pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Inclua um link para esta pergunta se ajudar a fornecer contexto. - [Da Revisão](/review/late-answers/386658)