# Como pegar estes dados do filter_input_array e inserir em outro arquivo php

Tags: php, input, post

Meu filter_input_array recebe todos os dados do form, porem não sei como pegar estes dados e inserir em outro arquivo php

```
<?php
    $data = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_DEFAULT);

    if (!empty($data['SendAddMsg'])) {
        //var_dump($data);
        //die();
        $query_msg = "INSERT INTO contacts_msgs (name, email, cpf, contato, created) VALUES (:name, :email, :cpf, :contato, NOW())";
        $add_msg = $conn->prepare($query_msg);

        $add_msg->bindParam(':name', $data['name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $add_msg->bindParam(':email', $data['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $add_msg->bindParam(':cpf', $data['cpf'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $add_msg->bindParam(':contato', $data['contato'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $add_msg->execute();
```

Comment: Possivelmente relacionado: [Quando e o porquê usar session_start? \[fechada\]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178666/3774)

Answer (score 0):

Caso 1 - Se você se refere a "outro arquivo" como sendo um arquivo na mesma requisição, então você pode criar uma função (ou uma classe com um método) no outro arquivo para receber o array como parâmetro. Feito isso basta dar um include ou require no arquivo que contém a função (ou classe) e chamar a função (ou instanciar a classe).

https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.include.php

Exemplo:

Arquivo 1 - Aquele que recebe a requisição:

```
<?php
    $data = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_DEFAULT);

    if (!empty($data['SendAddMsg'])) {
        //var_dump($data);
        //die();
        $query_msg = "INSERT INTO contacts_msgs (name, email, cpf, contato, created) VALUES (:name, :email, :cpf, :contato, NOW())";
        $add_msg = $conn->prepare($query_msg);

        $add_msg->bindParam(':name', $data['name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $add_msg->bindParam(':email', $data['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $add_msg->bindParam(':cpf', $data['cpf'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $add_msg->bindParam(':contato', $data['contato'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $add_msg->execute();

        //Chama o arquivo dois com a função a ser utilizada.
        require_once('arquivo2.php');

        //Chama a função e passa os valores como parâmetro.
        funexemplo($data);
    }
?>
```

Arquivo 2 - Aquele que contém a função que você quer utilizar os dados.

```
<?php
    funexemplo($data){
         //Utilize a variável "data" para utilizar os valores.
    }
?>
```

Caso 2 - Se você se refere a "outro arquivo" como sendo uma outra página que será carregada, então você pode deixar armazenado em Session ou Cookie, no PHP, ou em LocalStorage, no Javascript.

https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.session.php
https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.cookies.php

Exemplo:

Arquivo 1 - Aquele que recebe a primeira requisição:

```
<?php
    $data = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_DEFAULT);

    if (!empty($data['SendAddMsg'])) {
        //var_dump($data);
        //die();
        $query_msg = "INSERT INTO contacts_msgs (name, email, cpf, contato, created) VALUES (:name, :email, :cpf, :contato, NOW())";
        $add_msg = $conn->prepare($query_msg);

        $add_msg->bindParam(':name', $data['name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $add_msg->bindParam(':email', $data['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $add_msg->bindParam(':cpf', $data['cpf'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $add_msg->bindParam(':contato', $data['contato'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $add_msg->execute();

        //Armazena o valor em Cookie (Nesse exemplo ele tem validade de 30 dias).
        setcookie("cookie_teste", serialize($data), time() + (86400 * 30), "/");

    }
?>
```

Arquivo 2 - Aquele que recebe a segunda requisição (onde os dados precisam ser usados):

```
<?php
    $saved_data = unserialize($_COOKIE['cookie_teste']);

    var_dump($saved_data )
?>
```